# Setting Cross-origin-Embedder-Policy and Cross-origin-Opener-Policy headers in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I've been developping a website using express(NodeJS) for the backend and React for the frontend. I've come accross the issue where my application won't work on Firefox due to this error "ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined".
After having searched a bit online, it appears it has to do with CORS. I saw that on Chrome there is a warning about the use of SharedArrayBuffer as well.

So I read that I need to set those headers
̀`Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin  Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp`

But I am not sure on how to do that. On my backend I've been using the cors package to set my cors headers and options as such

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  credentials: true,
  'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
  'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'preflightContinue': false
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I've also tried using this method but it doesn't appear to work either :

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Cross-origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
  res.setHeader('Cross-origin-Opener-Policy','same-origin');
  next();
});
```

Am I totally missing something/misunderstanding?
It is my first time developping a web application and I am kind of lost at this point. Any help would be grately appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try to process options request in your custom middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Cross-origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
  res.setHeader('Cross-origin-Opener-Policy','same-origin');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200)
  } else {
    next()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what causes this, but for me using a different route worked

## Cross-origin isolation using node / express

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
  res.header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
  next();
});


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
// does **not** work, no cors headers in response

app.get('/app', async (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
// does work, cors headers in response as expected
```

Comment: Think it should be `res.setHeader` - that was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` must be set on the client website (client.example.com), i.e. the one consuming the backend resources.

The backend (api.example.com) should be setup to allow for CORS (for example using the `cors` package as you are) from the client's origin.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: client.example.com
```

If you are embedding images or `link` from the backend, then you would need to add the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute.

```
<img src="api.example.com/image.png" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="" />
```

If you are embedding an iframe, then the target of the iframe would need to add the `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin` and `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` headers on the backend (api.example.com) to allow other websites to embed from that resource. Note that this means anyone would be able to embed from your backend.

---

Note that I am not sure how this relates to the SharedArrayBuffer exception you are seeing.