# Helmet "crossOriginEmbedderPolicy" enable/disable for specific domains

Tags: node.js

Helmet: ^5.1.1

*Using NextJS with NodeJS.*

> Setting helmet's crossOriginEmbedderPolicy to false works to load the iframe.

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
  })
);
```

> But can something like below be done ?

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: {
      //disable for specific site
    }
  })
);
```

The following solutions didn't work for me:

1. [Setting Cross-origin-Embedder-Policy and Cross-origin-Opener-Policy headers in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67007822/setting-cross-origin-embedder-policy-and-cross-origin-opener-policy-headers-in-n)
2. [Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: how to allow only certain domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68654550/cross-origin-embedder-policy-how-to-allow-only-certain-domains)
3. https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your software architecture, but if you host many domains, you can introduce a configuration file in your application, like this:

config.json:

```
{
  "domain1": {
      crossOrigin: true
  },
  "domain2": {
      crossOrigin: false
  },
  "domain3" : {
     crossOrigin: true
  }
}
```

And then in your code for loading configuration:

```
const config  = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( __dirname + /config.json', 'utf8' ));
```

Finally, set the value:

```
const crossOrigin = config[request.headers.host].crossOrigin;
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: crossOrigin
  })
);
```